# Creating OneToOneField with base model

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

Sometimes in course of time model becomes too huge. There is a desire to split it on a several models and connect them with `OneToOneField`. Fields that uses most often, kept in primary model, other fields moves into other models.

However this approach becomes a headache when creating new instance of model. When you can initialize one model with one line:

```
MyModel.objects.create(foo=1, bar=2)
```

you needs at least two lines to initialize two models:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(foo=1, bar=2)
MyRelatedModel.objects.create(mymodel=instance, hello=3, world=4)
```

Is there a way to *simply* create two models in one line, or i should write my own auxiliary function for such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You should not split your models with onetooneField because of following reasons

- As you said there will be some extra code to manage them.
- Every time you query them you will have to make two queries instead of two.

Please don't forget that django models has two functions. The keep data related methods and they keep data model of your application. Some bussiness models have tables that have hundreds of fields. This is completely normal. If you really want to split them. you might want to check out abstract base classes. those are base classes for your model that does not have a seperate tables for themselves https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

But if you insist on going with oneToOne field you can wrap object creation code in one of the model's method like

```
MyMode.create(attr_for_model_A=1, attr_for_model_B=2)
```

Or you can overwrite default manager's create method to create two method instead of one
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets

In my opinion, non-of those will worth having small model code.

Comment: Well, i was thought that splitting table can increase "select" query speed, but i had just googled about it and realized that it isn't. Really, better to keep all data in one table.

Comment: Query speed might increase, If you query only one table but not the others. Because amount of data you query will be decreased. But you can  get same result by restricting result fields. You can do this with "only" or "defer" method of queryset(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only).  Here is some more info about query performence using "only" method. http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/django-orm-performance-tips-part-2/